# Make responsive browser window that shrinks according to aspect ratio in Canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I want to make a browser window like:

[image: browser window image]

I picked out this image from https://tailwindcss.com/

How do I make a responsive browser window that shrinks & grows when you resize the Chrome Browser's window in Canvas?

**Note:** I don't want to make the browser window's width equal to `window.innerWidth`. I want it to have size `1024*600` & maintain an aspect ratio of `16 / 9`.

I can't figure out the math. I also can't use [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) as there is no padding bottom to be used.

I even read https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ but it's not what I want.

I have `width`, `height` & `aspectRatio` & want to make a resposive rectangle without using `padding-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `width: 100%` to the element.

Comment: i forgot to mention the browser window must not be equal to `window.innerWidth` but rather have `1024*600` browser size & an aspect ratio of `16 / 9`....that would've been simpler...i'll add this to the question thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Oh okay thanks, sorry I didn't understand you :(